# JavaScript not altering CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My JavaScript is not correctly changing the actor-images display from "none" to "block" and I am unsure on what the problem is as this should be working correctly. I have tested this code within the web browser and the console reads back no errors, yet when in use, the images are not displaying and I can't figure out what the problem is.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', actorGallery);

function actorGallery() {
  var next = document.getElementById("next-button");
  var prev = document.getElementById("previous-button");
  var actorImages = document.getElementsByClassName("actor-images");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  var i;

  function showSlides(n) {

    if (n > actorImages.length) {
      slideNumber = 1
    }

    if (n < 1) {
      slideNumber = actorImages.length
    }

    for (i = 0; i < actorImages.length; i++) {
      actorImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    actorImages[slideNumber - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideNumber - 1].className += " active";
  }

  function slideMove(n) {
    showSlides(slideNumber += n);
  }

  var slideNumber = 1;
  showSlides(slideNumber);


  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideNumber = n);
  }
  /* End of Citation */

  prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (slideNumber != 1) {

      slideMove(-1);

    }


  });

  next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (slideNumber != actorImages.length - 1) {

      slideMove(+1);

    }

  });

  document.querySelectorAll(".dot").forEach(function(ele, i) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(i + 1);
      currentSlide(i + 1);
    })
  });

}
```

```css
.actor-images {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.dot-span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="actor-images">
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        1 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/frodo.jpg" alt="Elijah Wood - Frodo Baggins">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Elijah Wood - (Frodo Baggins)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        2 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/samwise-gamgee-samwise-gamgee.jpg" alt="Sean Astin - Samwise Gamgee">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Sean Astin - (Samwise Gamgee)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        3 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/1e53eeea02819531453539bdf3b1d16f.jpg" alt="Dominic Monaghan - Meriadoc 'Merry' Brandybuck">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Dominic Monaghan - (Meriadoc 'Merry' Brandybuck)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        4 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Pippin_Took_profile.jpg" alt="Billy Boyd - Peregrin Took">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Billy Boyd - (Peregrin Took)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        5 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/aragorn-lord-of-the-rings.jpg" alt="Viggo Mortensen - Aragorn">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Viggo Mortensen - (Aragorn)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        6 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Orlando-Bloom-as-Legolas-Greenleaf-The-Lord-of-the-Rings-Fellowship-of-the-Ring-Bow.jpg" alt="Orlando Bloom - Legolas Greenleaf">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Orlando Bloom - (Legolas Greenleaf)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        7 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Gimli.jpg" alt="John Rhys-Davies - Gimli">
      <div class="image-caption">
        John Rhys Davis - (Gimli)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        8 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/gandalfnod.gif" alt="Sir Ian McKellen - Gandalf the Grey/White">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Sir Ian Mckellen - (Gandalf the Grey/White)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        9 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/bilbobaggins.jpg" alt="Ian Holm - Bilbo Baggins">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Ian Holm - (Bilbo Baggins)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        10 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Seanbean_boromir.jpg" alt="Sean Bean - Boromir">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Sean Bean - (Boromir)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        11 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/elrond_lotr_090117.jpg" alt="Hugo Weaving - Lord Elrond">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Hugo Weaving - (Lord Elrond)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        12 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/theoden.jpg" alt="Bernard Hill - King Theoden">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Bernard Hill - (King Theoden)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        13 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/6f4f046b6bbb57dcaf0566897c6f9a1e--arwen-undomiel-liv-tyler.jpg" alt="Liv Tyler - Arwen">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Liv Tyler - (Arwen)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        14 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Eomer_King.jpg" alt="Karl Urban - Eomer">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Karl Urban - (Eomer)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        15 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/tumblr_static_eowyn.jpg" alt="Miranda Otto - Eowyn">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Miranda Otto - (Eowyn)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        16 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/Faramir.jpg" alt="David Wenham - Faramir">
      <div class="image-caption">
        David Wenham - (Faramir)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        17 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/gollum.jpg" alt="Andy Serkis - Gollum/Smeagol">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Andy Serkis - (Gollum/Smeagol) (Motion Capture and Voice)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actor-images fade">
      <div class="image-number">
        18 / 18
      </div>
      <img src="img/saruman.jpg" alt="Christopher Lee - Saruman the White">
      <div class="image-caption">
        Christopher Lee - (Saruman the White)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="previous-button">&#10094;</a>
  <a id="next-button">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="dot-span">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is in binding the event

Comment: As in adding an event listener?

Comment: Yes, may be it need to be like this: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', actorGallery());

Comment: also there is no elements with class 'dot' in your html and this cause an error on this line dots[slideNumber-1].className += " active"; because dots length is always 0

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the HTML for the dots, they work as intended, though making your suggested change gives me the error; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined, which appears at your suggested line and at lines 34 and 43

Comment: yes, because dots[slideNumber-1] is undefined , dots are zero length

Comment: Added the code relating to the dots if that is any extra help?

Comment: ad it seems to be working now for me

Comment: I do not understand how it works for you, yet the console still gives me the same error that I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I ran it in the Snippet in the question and it works, just the images are not showing because of the Images urls, and it gives no errors

Comment: That's what confuses me, as before I had some functionality with my JS with the buttons displaying corresponding functions with the dots, but now I don't have that anymore, and I can only assume that the error I mentioned before is the catalyst and I am unsure on how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After minutes of debugging

You container and the container that holder that divs for the images have the same className so when this code

`actorImages[slideNumber - 1].style.display = "block";`

is performed the main container shows up and when you click next it the codes hides the main container that holds the images and the set the first img to block but since the container is hidden we can't see the img so i would suggest the following :

Add another class for your main container like this

```
.maincontainer{
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

then add another class for the sub containers

```
  .actor-images {
    display: none;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

EDIT :

your new CSS

```
.actor-images {
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main{
height: 150px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.dot-span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Your new HTML :

```
  <div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          1 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/frodo.jpg" alt="Elijah Wood - Frodo Baggins">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Elijah Wood - (Frodo Baggins)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          2 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/samwise-gamgee-samwise-gamgee.jpg" alt="Sean Astin - Samwise Gamgee">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Sean Astin - (Samwise Gamgee)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          3 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/1e53eeea02819531453539bdf3b1d16f.jpg" alt="Dominic Monaghan - Meriadoc 'Merry' Brandybuck">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Dominic Monaghan - (Meriadoc 'Merry' Brandybuck)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          4 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Pippin_Took_profile.jpg" alt="Billy Boyd - Peregrin Took">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Billy Boyd - (Peregrin Took)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          5 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/aragorn-lord-of-the-rings.jpg" alt="Viggo Mortensen - Aragorn">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Viggo Mortensen - (Aragorn)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          6 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Orlando-Bloom-as-Legolas-Greenleaf-The-Lord-of-the-Rings-Fellowship-of-the-Ring-Bow.jpg" alt="Orlando Bloom - Legolas Greenleaf">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Orlando Bloom - (Legolas Greenleaf)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          7 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Gimli.jpg" alt="John Rhys-Davies - Gimli">
        <div class="image-caption">
          John Rhys Davis - (Gimli)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          8 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/gandalfnod.gif" alt="Sir Ian McKellen - Gandalf the Grey/White">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Sir Ian Mckellen - (Gandalf the Grey/White)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          9 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/bilbobaggins.jpg" alt="Ian Holm - Bilbo Baggins">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Ian Holm - (Bilbo Baggins)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          10 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Seanbean_boromir.jpg" alt="Sean Bean - Boromir">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Sean Bean - (Boromir)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          11 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/elrond_lotr_090117.jpg" alt="Hugo Weaving - Lord Elrond">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Hugo Weaving - (Lord Elrond)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          12 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/theoden.jpg" alt="Bernard Hill - King Theoden">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Bernard Hill - (King Theoden)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          13 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/6f4f046b6bbb57dcaf0566897c6f9a1e--arwen-undomiel-liv-tyler.jpg" alt="Liv Tyler - Arwen">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Liv Tyler - (Arwen)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          14 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Eomer_King.jpg" alt="Karl Urban - Eomer">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Karl Urban - (Eomer)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          15 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/tumblr_static_eowyn.jpg" alt="Miranda Otto - Eowyn">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Miranda Otto - (Eowyn)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          16 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/Faramir.jpg" alt="David Wenham - Faramir">
        <div class="image-caption">
          David Wenham - (Faramir)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          17 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/gollum.jpg" alt="Andy Serkis - Gollum/Smeagol">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Andy Serkis - (Gollum/Smeagol) (Motion Capture and Voice)
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actor-images fade">
        <div class="image-number">
          18 / 18
        </div>
        <img src="img/saruman.jpg" alt="Christopher Lee - Saruman the White">
        <div class="image-caption">
          Christopher Lee - (Saruman the White)
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="previous-button">&#10094;</a>
    <a id="next-button">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="dot-span">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's also brought me no joy, I am probably doing something wrong but I have amended my CSS as so and alter my HTML so the images are located within the new container, yet still no result.

Comment: Just change the main div class name from actor-images to maincontainer then add the css as shown above

Comment: That's worked brilliantly! I added extra code to make sure the images properly fit the new container. Thanks for your help!